# Get the name of local table and linked table in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have five tables in my application in which two are local table and three are linked table, I'm not sure about my code how to get name of table. I want a code for provide me name of both type of table name separately using for loop.

Table Name

```
LocalTable1
LocalTable2
LinkTable1
LinkTable2
LinkTable3
```

Code

```
Dim td As TableDef
Dim stConnect As String
For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
  Debug.Print td.Name 
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the source table name:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        Debug.Print tdf.Name & IIf(tdf.SourceTableName <> "", "  source table: " _
            & tdf.SourceTableName, "")
    End If
Next
```