# How to programmatically update all linked table references in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, auto-update

I would like to update the linked table references of 60+ tables/excel files in a MS Accecss database:

[image]

However I do not want to go into all 60+ manually as the file-path will simply need to change "F:"..." to "E:...".

How can this mass reassignment be done programmatically?

Comment: The only programmatic way I know is to delete all the linked tables and the re-link them. There is probably a way to read linked tables and their properties off the system tables so you could use that to do it, but I have never done it.

Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579591/get-the-name-of-local-table-and-linked-table-in-vba

Answer (score 3):

Is this a one shot? If yes, this might be overkill and would take some time to poerfection, but on the upside, you wont need a separate table to keep your references
If you are familiar with VBA you can use something like this:

```
Dim td As DAO.TableDef
Dim strPath as string

For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If (td.Attributes And dbAttachedTable) = dbAttachedTable Then
        strPath = Mid(td.Connect, 11)
        If Left(strPath, 1) = "E" Then
            strPath = "F" & Mid(strPath, 2)
            td.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strPath
            td.RefreshLink
        End If
    End If
Next
```

That is for ODBC-Databases without password. If your connection-strings are more complicated, you would have to adjust. 
Here is a list of all possible connection-strings.
[Microsoft DAO Connection Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193791.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

The following code does 3 things:

1. It gets the path for the linked tables from a table "linked table source" based on the location of the current db - sometimes I have it on my local drive and sometimes it's on a network server.
2. It updates the references to the source db - I store common codes in that library where I can keep a single copy for use in all my apps
3. It updates every linked table to the source defined in the table - but only for tables likes to the db with the "Common Tables" name

> ```
> Function relink_tables()
>
> If Left(CurrentDb().Name, 2) = "C:" Or Left(CurrentDb().Name, 2) = "B:" Then
>     Source = "local"
>     Else: Source = "network"
>     End If
> Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from [linked table source] where source='" & Source & "'")
> Source = rs.Fields("path")
>
> For Each R In References
>     If InStr(R.Name, "Common Tables") > 0 Then Application.References.Remove R
>     Next R
> Application.References.AddFromFile Source
>
> x = 0
> Set TDefs = CurrentDb().TableDefs
> For Each table In TDefs
>     If InStr(table.Connect, "Common Tables") = 0 Then GoTo NT
>     table.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & Source
>     table.RefreshLink
>     x = x + 1
> NT:
>     Next table
> Finish:
> MsgBox "remapped " & x & " tables"
> End Function
> ```

Comment: Where is table": "linked table source"

Comment: It's in the current db where I run this code.  The fields are source and path.  Source is either "local" or "network" and the path is the full path to the source db for the linked tables.  You may not need this if you always link to the same location, or want a msgbox to prompt for the location.

Comment: @Don George: Don't you link every table to the same source here ?